# Blogger Meta Description missing

Tags: html, blogger, meta-tags, meta

I have made a Blog on Blogspot and it worked perfectly.

Recently I changed HTTP to HTTPS and made a few tweaks to the code, which obviously messed up my meta tags..

Link to the blog -
www.theblockbay.com

Link to the original template - https://btemplates.com/2016/blogger-template-aurora-2/

My HTML head tag

```
<head>
<link href='https://www.theblockbay.com/favicon.ico' rel='icon' type='image/x-icon'/>
<meta content='blogger' name='generator'/>
<link href='https://www.theblockbay.com/feeds/posts/default' rel='alternate' title='theBlockBay | Cryptocurrency Stories That Matter - Atom' type='application/atom+xml'/>
<link href='https://www.theblockbay.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss' rel='alternate' title='theBlockBay | Cryptocurrency Stories That Matter - RSS' type='application/rss+xml'/>
<link href='https://www.blogger.com/feeds/3119964400244253328/posts/default' rel='service.post' title='theBlockBay | Cryptocurrency Stories That Matter - Atom' type='application/atom+xml'/>
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.blogger.com/static/v1/jsbin/2591933621-ieretrofit.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<meta expr:content='data:blog.url' name='og:url:domain'/>
<!--[if IE]> <script>(function(){var html5=(&quot;abbr,article,aside,audio,canvas,datalist,details,&quot;+&quot;figure,footer,header,hgroup,mark,menu,meter,nav,output,&quot;+&quot;progress,section,time,video&quot;).split(&#39;,&#39;);for(var i=0;i&lt;html5.length;i++){document.createElement(html5[i]);}try{document.execCommand(&#39;BackgroundImageCache&#39;,false,true);}catch(e){}})();</script> <![endif]-->
<meta content='IE=edge,chrome=1' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0' name='viewport'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:site_name'/>
<meta content='blog' property='og:type'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.canonicalUrl.https' property='og:url'/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' property='og:description'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.postImageUrl != &quot;&quot;'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl.https' property='og:image'/>
<b:else/>
<meta content='blog' property='og:type'/>
</b:if>
<link href='https://www.theblockbay.com' hreflang='en' rel='alternate'/>
<meta content='89de26ef00baf4a13bb347a1c5216bc9' name='p:domain_verify'/>
<meta content='a6db248b73e9278c' name='yandex-verification'/>
<meta content='3818CAF56D216A086CAE2401A78EBED3' name='msvalidate.01'/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;archive&quot;'>
<meta content='noindex,nofollow' name='robots'/>
<b:else/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;error_page&quot;'>
<meta content='noindex,nofollow' name='robots'/>
<b:else/>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.homepageUrl == data:blog.url'>
<meta content='index,follow' name='robots'/>
<b:else/>
<meta content='noindex,nofollow' name='robots'/>
</b:if>
<b:else/>
<meta content='index,follow' name='robots'/>
</b:if>
</b:if>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.newerPageUrl'>
<link expr:href='data:blog.newerPageUrl' rel='next'/>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.olderPageUrl'>
<link expr:href='data:blog.olderPageUrl' rel='prev'/>
</b:if>
</b:if>
<b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:blog.homepageUrl'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName + &quot;: &quot; + data:blog.title' property='og:title'/>
<title><data:blog.pageName/> / <data:blog.title/></title>
<b:else/>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.pageTitle' property='og:title'/>
<title>
<b:if cond='data:blog.homepageUrl == data:blog.url'>
<data:blog.title/>
<b:else/>
<data:blog.pageName/> | <data:blog.title/>
</b:if>
</title>
</b:if>
<b:skin><![CDATA[<b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription != 
&quot;&quot;'>
<meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' 
name='description'/>
</b:if>/*<Variable name="keycolor" description="Main Color" type="color" default="#ffffff" value="#ffffff"/><Group description="Page Text" selector="body"><Variable name="body.font" description="Font" type="font" default="normal normal 14px Open Sans,sans-serif" value="normal normal 15px Open Sans,sans-serif"/><Variable name="body.text.color" description="Text Color" type="color" default="#1a1a1a" value="#000000"/></Group><Group description="Backgrounds" selector=".body-fauxcolumns-outer"><Variable name="background.color" description="Body Background" type="color" default="#ffffff" value="#ffffff"/><Variable name="menu.color" description="Menu Background" type="color" default="#e0e3e8" value="#f3f3f3"/></Group><Group description="Blog Title" selector=".header h1"><Variable name="header.font" description="Font" type="font" default="200 60px Raleway, sans-serif" value="normal bold 60px Raleway, sans-serif"/><Variable name="header.text.color" description=" Blog Title Color" type="color" default="#1a1a1a" value="#000000"/></Group><Group description="Blog Description" selector=".header .description"><Variable name="description.text.color" description="Description Color" type="color" default="#1a1a1a" value="#1a1a1a"/><Variable name="description.font" description="Description Font" type="font" default="normal 12px Open Sans, sans-serif" value="normal normal 16px Open Sans, sans-serif"/></Group><Group description="Accents" selector=".outer-wrapper"><Variable name="border.color" description="Border Color" type="color" default="#1a1a1a" value="#666666"/><Variable name="social.color" description="Social Icons Color" type="color" default="#1a1a1a" value="#1a1a1a"/></Group><Group description="Links" selector=".main-outer"><Variable name="link.color" description="Link Color" type="color" default="#c2bfc5" value="#b4b4b4"/><Variable name="link.visited.color" description="Visited Color" type="color" default="#c2bfc5" value="#000000"/><Variable name="link.hover.color" description="Hover Color" type="color" default="#e0e3e8" value="#6a6a6a"/></Group><Group description="Menu Text" selector=".tabs-inner .widget li a"><Variable name="tabs.font" description="Menu Font" type="font" default="400 11px Open Sans, sans-serif" value="normal normal 12px Open Sans, sans-serif"/><Variable name="tabs.text.color" description="Menu Text Color" type="color" default="#1a1a1a" value="#666666"/><Variable name="tabs.selected.text.color" description="Menu Selected Color" type="color" default="#ffffff" value="#444444"/></Group><Group description="Post Title" selector="h1.post-title, .comments h4"><Variable name="post.title.font" description="Post Title Font" type="font" default="600 16px Open Sans, sans-serif" value="normal bold 24px Open Sans,sans-serif"/><Variable name="post.title.color" description="Post Title Color" type="color" default="#1a1a1a" value="#373737"/></Group><Group description="Gadgets" selector="h2"><Variable name="widget.title.font" description="Sidebar Title Font" type="font" default="600 15px Open Sans, sans-serif" value="normal bold 14px Open Sans, sans-serif"/><Variable name="widget.title.text.color" description="Sidebar Title Color" type="color" default="#1a1a1a" value="#1b1b1b"/></Group><Variable name="startSide" description="Side where text starts in blog language" type="automatic" default="left"/><Variable name="endSide" description="Side where text ends in blog language" type="automatic" default="right"/>*/------------------------------------------------------*/html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,font,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;font-size:100%;vertical-align:baseline;background:transparent}body{line-height:1}blockquote,q{quotes:none}blockquote:before,blockquote:after,q:before,q:after{content:'';content:none}:focus{outline:0}ins{text-decoration:none}del{text-decoration:line-through}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0}#navbar,#Attribution1,.post-icons,.post-author.vcard,.post-timestamp,.feed-links{display:none}body{font:$(body.font);color:$(body.text.color);background:$(background.color);text-align:justify;overflow-x:hidden}html body{width:100%}.outer-wrapper{margin:0 auto}.content-wrapper{margin-bottom:30px}.column-center-outer,.column-right-outer{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}.column-center-outer{width:75%;float:left}.column-right-outer{width:25%;float:right}a:link{text-decoration:none;color:$(link.color)}a:visited{text-decoration:none;color:$(link.visited.color)}a:hover{text-decoration:none;color:$(link.hover.color)}hr{border:1px solid $(link.color);width:30%;margin:15px auto}.header-wrapper{_background-image:none;max-width:960px;margin:100px auto;padding:50px 0}.Header h1{font:$(header.font);color:$(header.text.color);text-align:center}.Header h1 a{color:$(header.text.color)}#Header1_headerimg{margin:0 auto;max-width:100%;height:auto}.Header .description{color:$(description.text.color);font:$(description.font);margin-bottom:25px;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:2px}.header-inner .Header .titlewrapper{padding:80px 0 40px}.header-inner .Header .descriptionwrapper{padding:0;margin:0;letter-spacing:1px}.header-wrapper .widget{margin:0}.PageList h2{display:none}.PageList{background:$(menu.color);position:fixed;top:0;left:0;z-index:999;width:100%}ul.dropdown{padding:10px 0!important;text-align:center;margin:0 auto!important}ul.dropdown li{text-align:left;display:inline-block;position:relative;padding:0 15px;cursor:pointer}ul.dropdown li a,.dropit .dropit-submenu span{font:$(tabs.font);color:$(tabs.text.color);text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:2px}.dropit .dropit-trigger{position:relative}.dropit .dropit-submenu{padding:15px 0 0;background:$(menu.color);position:absolute;top:100%;left:0;z-index:1000;display:none;min-width:150px;list-style:none;margin:0;visibility:hidden}.dropit .dropit-submenu li{padding:10px 15px;display:block}.dropit .dropit-submenu li:hover{background:$(background.color)}.dropit .dropit-submenu li a:hover{color:$(link.color)}.dropit .dropit-open .dropit-submenu{display:block;visibility:visible}.PageList ul li.selected a,.PageList ul li a:hover{color:$(tabs.selected.text.color);position:relative;z-index:1}li.buscador{vertical-align:middle}.search-form{background:transparent;position:relative}#searchform fieldset{background:transparent;border:1px solid transparent;transition:all .6s ease-out;-o-transition:all .6s ease-out;-moz-transition:all .6s ease-out;-webkit-transition:all .6s ease-out;padding:5px;width:80px}#searchform fieldset:hover{background:$(menu.color);width:170px;border:$(menu.color);border-left:1px solid $(border.color);border-right:1px solid $(border.color);opacity:1}#search{background:transparent;border:0;float:left;margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;font:$(tabs.font)}.search-form input::-webkit-input-placeholder:before{content:"\f002";font-family:FontAwesome;color:$(tabs.text.color);padding-right:5px}.search-form input::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:$(tabs.text.color);letter-spacing:2px;opacity:1}.search-form input:-moz-placeholder:before{content:"\f002";font-family:FontAwesome;color:$(tabs.text.color);padding-right:5px}.search-form input:-moz-placeholder{color:$(tabs.text.color);letter-spacing:2px;opacity:1}.search-form input::-moz-placeholder:before{content:"\f002";font-family:FontAwesome;color:$(tabs.text.color);padding-right:5px}.search-form input::-moz-placeholder{color:$(tabs.text.color);letter-spacing:2px;opacity:1}.search-form input:-ms-input-placeholder:before{content:"\f002";font-family:FontAwesome;color:$(tabs.text.color);padding-right:5px}.search-form input:-ms-input-placeholder{color:$(tabs.text.color);letter-spacing:2px}[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{transition:opacity .5s .5s ease;opacity:0}[placeholder]:focus::-moz-placeholder{transition:opacity .5s .5s ease;opacity:0}input:-webkit-autofill{-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 0 1000px #fff inset}.slicknav_menu{display:none}.slicknav_btn{position:relative;display:block;vertical-align:middle;padding:15px;line-height:1.9;cursor:pointer}.slicknav_btn .slicknav_icon-bar+.slicknav_icon-bar{margin-top:.188em}.slicknav_menu{*zoom:1}.slicknav_menu .slicknav_menutxt{display:block;line-height:1.188em}.slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon{margin:0;display:none}.slicknav_menu .slicknav_no-text{margin:0}.slicknav_menu .slicknav_icon-bar{display:none}.slicknav_menu:before{content:" ";display:table}.slicknav_menu:after{content:" ";display:table;clear:both}.slicknav_nav{clear:both;text-align:center}.slicknav_nav ul{display:block}.slicknav_nav li{display:block}.slicknav_nav .slicknav_arrow{font-size:.8em;margin:0 0 0 .4em;font-family:FontAwesome}.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item{cursor:pointer}.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item a{display:inline}.slicknav_nav .slicknav_row{display:block}.slicknav_nav a{display:block}.slicknav_nav .slicknav_parent-link a{display:inline}.slicknav_brand{float:left}.slicknav_menu{font-size:16px;box-sizing:border-box;background:$(menu.color);padding:0}.slicknav_menu *{box-sizing:border-box}.slicknav_menu .slicknav_menutxt{color:$(tabs.text.color);text-align:center;font-family:FontAwesome}.slicknav_btn{margin:0 auto;text-decoration:none}.slicknav_nav{color:$(tabs.text.color);font:$(tabs.font);margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;overflow:hidden;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:1px}.slicknav_nav ul{list-style:none;overflow:hidden;padding:0;margin:0}.slicknav_nav .slicknav_row{padding:5px 10px;margin:2px 5px}.slicknav_nav a{padding:5px 10px;margin:2px 5px;text-decoration:none;color:$(tabs.text.color)}.slicknav_nav a:hover{color:$(keycolor)}.slicknav_nav .slicknav_txtnode{margin-left:15px}.slicknav_nav .slicknav_item a{padding:0;margin:0}.slicknav_nav .slicknav_parent-link a{padding:0;margin:0}.slicknav_brand{color:#fff;font-size:18px;line-height:30px;padding:7px 12px;height:44px}h2{margin:0 0 10px;font:$(widget.title.font);color:$(widget.title.text.color);text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:2px}h3,h4{font:$(widget.title.font);color:$(widget.title.text.color);letter-spacing:2px}h3{font-size:18px}h4{font-size:16px}h2.date-header{margin:0 auto 10px;border-bottom:0;font:$(tabs.font)}.main-wrapper{max-width:960px;margin:0 auto}.main.section{margin:0 70px 0 0}.post{margin:0 0 100px}h1.post-title,.comments h4{font:$(post.title.font);text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:1px;text-align:center;color:$(post.title.color)}h1.post-title a{color:$(post.title.color)}.location{margin:15px auto;text-align:center}.post-location{font:$(tabs.font);text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:2px}.post-location a{color:$(link.hover.color)}.post-body{font-size:100%;line-height:1.9;position:relative;margin-bottom:30px}.post-body img,.post-body .tr-caption-container{width:100%;height:auto}.post-body img:hover{opacity:.95}.post-body blockquote{margin:20px 0;line-height:1.8em;font-size:14px;font-style:italic;border:1px solid $(border.color);padding:35px}.post-body iframe{width:100%;height:422px}.post-header{margin:0 0 1.5em;line-height:1.6;font-size:100%}.jump-link{margin:25px auto 40px;text-align:center}.jump-link a{border:1px solid $(border.color);font:$(tabs.font);padding:15px;text-transform:uppercase;color:$(border.color);letter-spacing:2px}.jump-link a:hover{background:$(link.hover.color);color:$(keycolor);border:1px solid $(link.hover.color)}.post-footer{margin:35px 0;padding:0;font:$(tabs.font);line-height:1.8;letter-spacing:2px;text-transform:uppercase;text-align:center}.post-footer-line>*{margin:0}.comment-link{font:$(tabs.font)}.post-share-buttons.goog-inline-block,.post-footer-line.post-footer-line-1{text-align:center}.share .fa{font-size:13px;color:$(border.color)}.post-share-buttons{position:relative;text-align:center;top:1px}.share-button{background:none!important;padding:0 5px}span.post-labels{display:none}.related-posts{text-align:center;width:100%;margin:2em 0;float:left}.related-posts h5{font:$(post.title.font);letter-spacing:1px;margin:0 0 10px;text-transform:uppercase}.related-posts ul li{list-style:none;margin:0 26px 0 0;float:left;width:48%;text-align:center}.related-posts ul li:last-child{margin:0}.related-posts ul li img{width:100%;height:auto!important}.related-posts ul li img:hover{opacity:.95}.related-posts ul li a{font:$(tabs.font);color:$(post.title.color);text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:1px}.comments .comments-content .icon.blog-author{background-repeat:no-repeat}.comments .continue{background:$(background.color)}.comment-header{padding-bottom:20px;margin-top:40px;font:$(tabs.font);text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:2px}.comments .comments-content .user{font-weight:400}.comment-content{font:$(body.font);line-height:1.8em;color:$(body.text.color);padding-bottom:15px}.comment-actions{font-family:$(tabs.font)!important;letter-spacing:2px;font-size:80%;text-transform:uppercase}.comment-actions a:link{color:$(link.color)}.comment-actions a:hover{color:$(link.hover.color)}.avatar-image-container{border:0;padding:0}.thread-toggle{font:$(tabs.font);letter-spacing:2px;font-size:80%;text-transform:uppercase}.continue{display:inline-block;font:$(tabs.font);letter-spacing:2px;font-size:80%;text-transform:uppercase;padding:2px}#sidebar-right-1.sidebar.section{width:100%;margin:0 auto;padding:0;text-align:center}.sidebar .widget{border:1px solid $(border.color);padding:25px}.sidebar hr{margin:15px auto}.sidebar img{max-width:100%;height:auto}.widget{margin:30px 0}.widget ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}.widget li{margin:0;padding:0 0 .25em;text-indent:0;line-height:1.5em}.widget .popular-posts ul{list-style:none}.LinkList ul{overflow:hidden;line-height:0;text-align:center!important;margin:17px 0 0!important}.LinkList ul li{display:inline-block}.LinkList ul li a{letter-spacing:2px;display:inline-block;cursor:pointer;padding:0 10px;line-height:1.8;text-align:center;position:relative;z-index:1;color:$(social.color)}.LinkList ul li a:hover{color:$(link.hover.color)}.FollowByEmail .follow-by-email-inner{border-bottom:2px solid $(link.color)}.FollowByEmail .follow-by-email-inner .follow-by-email-address{text-align:left;width:90%;background:transparent;padding:10px 0;color:$(link.hover.color);border:0;font:$(tabs.font);text-transform:uppercase;margin-left:0;letter-spacing:1px}.FollowByEmail .follow-by-email-inner .follow-by-email-submit{background:transparent;width:10%;margin:0;padding:0;color:$(link.color);font-size:15px;font-family:FontAwesome}.follow-by-email-submit:focus{outline:0;border:0}.FollowByEmail input::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:$(tabs.text.color);letter-spacing:2px;opacity:1}.FollowByEmail input:-moz-placeholder{color:$(tabs.text.color);letter-spacing:2px;opacity:1}.FollowByEmail input::-moz-placeholder{color:$(tabs.text.color);letter-spacing:2px;opacity:1}.FollowByEmail input:-ms-input-placeholder{color:$(tabs.text.color);letter-spacing:2px}.popular-posts li:first-child .item-thumbnail,.popular-posts li:first-child .item-snippet{display:block}.PopularPosts ul li{margin:0 0 15px!important;overflow:hidden;padding:0!important;border:0}.popular-posts ul li:last-child{margin-bottom:0}.PopularPosts .item-thumbnail{margin:0!important;float:none!important}.PopularPosts ul li img{display:block;padding:0;max-width:100%;height:auto;margin-bottom:5px}.PopularPosts .item-title a{color:$(post.title.color);font:$(tabs.font);line-height:1.8;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:1px}.PopularPosts .item-title a:hover{color:$(link.hover.color)}.PopularPosts .item-snippet{display:none}.widget .widget-item-control a img{width:18px;height:18px}#BlogArchive1.widget.BlogArchive{border:0;padding:0}#BlogArchive1 hr{display:none}#BlogArchive1 h2{display:none}#BlogArchive1_ArchiveMenu{width:100%;font:$(tabs.font);text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:2px;color:$(border.color);border:1px solid $(border.color);padding:15px 5px}#blog-pager{margin:50px auto}.blog-pager-older-link,.home-link,.blog-pager-newer-link{color:$(border.color);font-size:20px;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:2px}.status-msg-wrap{width:100%;margin:50px 0;top:-50px}.status-msg-body{background:$(background.color);padding:0;font:$(post.title.font);text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:2px}.status-msg-border{border:0}.status-msg-bg{background-color:transparent}.footer-outer{border-top:0;width:100%;margin:0 auto}#footer.footer.section{margin:0}.footer-outer .widget{margin:0}.footer-outer h2{display:none}.bottom{width:100%;background:$(menu.color);padding:50px 0;text-align:center;margin:0 auto}.bottom-credits{margin:0 auto;color:$(tabs.text.color);text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:3px;padding:0;font-size:9px!important;font:$(tabs.font)}.bottom-credits a{color:$(tabs.text.color)}.bottom .fa{margin:15px auto;font-size:15px;display:block}.go-top{position:fixed;bottom:4em;right:1em;color:$(link.color);font-size:20px;display:none;margin:0}@media screen and (max-width:900px){.content-wrapper{margin:0 15px}.column-center-outer{width:65%;float:left}.column-right-outer{width:30%;float:right}.main.section{margin:0}.LinkList ul li a{padding:0 5px}.related-posts ul li{margin:0 15px 0 0}#blog-pager{margin-bottom:50px}}@media screen and (max-width:650px){.header-wrapper{margin:50px auto}.column-center-outer,.column-right-outer{width:100%;float:none;clear:both}.slicknav_menu{display:inherit}.PageList{display:none}li.buscador{display:none}#sidebar-right-1.sidebar.section{margin:50px auto;width:75%}}@media screen and (max-width:500px){.header-wrapper{margin:50px auto}.related-posts ul li{width:100%}.post-share-buttons.goog-inline-block{margin-left:0}#sidebar-right-1.sidebar.section{width:100%}}h2{color:#000;font-size:24px}h4{font-size:14px;margin-bottom:1.5em;color:#666;]]></b:skin>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'/>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'
```

Also, if anyone would know, I have a problem setting thumbnail pictures, when I'm sharing my posts it sometimes add wrong picture, or when I share the homepage, its without picture, and I would like it to be logo.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Some meta tags are related to **SEO** and some related to **https** ! if you need meta for description here it is

```
<title></title>
<meta content='' name='keywords'/>
<meta content='' name='description'/>
<meta content='website' property='og:type'/> 
<meta add-site-url='' content='' property='og:url'/>
```